# Sed fails to update long text

Tags: bash, sed

Consider test file *csf.conf*:

```
CC_DENY = ""
```

Running the command:

```
sed -i -E 's/(CC_DENY *= *")[^"]+/\1AR,BE,CL,CN,CO,CS,ES,FR,GR,HK,IT,KO,PA,PE,PH,PL,RS,RU,SG,SK,TH,UA,VN,AE,AF,AL,AS,AZ,BA,BD,BF,BH,BJ,BN,CI,DJ,EG,EH,ER,ET,GM,GN,GW,IQ,IR,IS,JO,KG,KM,KW,KZ,LB,LY,MC,MK,ML,MR,MV,MY,NE,NG,OM,PK,PS,QA,SA,SD,SL,SN,SO,SY,TD,TJ,TM,TN,TR,UZ,XK,YE,YT/g' csf.conf
```

Does not replace the match inside the file. Output should look like this:

```
CC_DENY="AR,BE,CL,CN,CO,CS,ES,FR,GR,HK,IT,KO,PA,PE,PH,PL,RS,RU,SG,SK,TH,UA,VN,AE,AF,AL..."
```

Sed v4.2.2, same result on Debian 8, and Centos 7

Comment: The pattern `[^"]+` requires one or more non-double-quotes after the double quote.  `CC_DENY = ""` doesn't have one or more non-double quotes after the first.  The pattern should not be substituted.  Replace the `+` with `*`, for example, and it works fine.

Comment: @SamuelJackson, note that the variable value in the config file may contain a double quote as well as `CC_DENY ="`. I have tried to make better regex in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with long text, your regexp just doesn't match the content of your file. Change `[^"]+` to `[^"]*` so it'll match even when there's nothing between the double quotes `""`. Look:

```
$ cat csf.conf
CC_DENY = ""

$ sed -E 's/(CC_DENY *= *")[^"]+/\1foo/' csf.conf
CC_DENY = ""

$ sed -E 's/(CC_DENY *= *")[^"]*/\1foo/' csf.conf
CC_DENY = "foo"
```

wrt the comment below from the OP that this sed command works:

```
$ cat file
LF_SPI = ""

$ sed -E 's/(LF_SPI *= *\")[^\"]+/\1blah/g' file
LF_SPI = ""
```

Clearly and predictably, no it does not. It simply can't because the regexp metacharacter `+` means `1 or more` so `[^\"]+` states there must be at least one non-`"` after the `"` and that just does not exist in the input file. There is no reason to escape the double quotes btw.

Comment: `s/(LF_SPI *= *\")[^\"]+/\1blah/g` matches `LF_SPI = ""`  no problem

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the current variable value in the file is empty. Then your regular expression doesn't match because `[^"]+` means "any character, except double quote repeated one or more times".

You might fix it by replacing `+` quantifier with `*` (zero or more times). But suppose the value contains a double quote:

```
CC_DENY = "\""
```

Then the `[^"]*` will match everything until it gets to the double quote within the value.

Thus, I suggest the following command:

```
# Put the variable value here
value='AR,BE\\" ... YE,YT';

sed -i -r 's/^( *CC_DENY *= *").*"/\1'"$value"'"/' csf.conf
```

Also note, that the expression above uses an anchor for the beginning of the line. Otherwise, it will fail to match *as expected*, if such a `CC_DENY = "...` exists in the variable value in the configuration file: `CC_DENY = "SOMETHING_CC_DENY = \"value\""`.

Comment: Thank you for the `^` preceding char.  Must have.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is certainly the wrong tool for this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = "\42"
}
$2 = "AR,BE,CL,CN,CO,CS,ES,FR,GR,HK,IT,KO,PA,PE,PH,PL,RS,RU,SG,SK,TH,UA,VN," \
"AE,AF,AL,AS,AZ,BA,BD,BF,BH,BJ,BN,CI,DJ,EG,EH,ER,ET,GM,GN,GW,IQ,IR,IS,JO,KG," \
"KM,KW,KZ,LB,LY,MC,MK,ML,MR,MV,MY,NE,NG,OM,PK,PS,QA,SA,SD,SL,SN,SO,SY,TD,TJ," \
"TM,TN,TR,UZ,XK,YE,YT"
```

Comment: Sorry you came a bit late to the party.  This would work if that config variable was the only one being replaced (or the first one).  This is part of a much larger script where this variable is deep within a trove of other variables, some being replaced, while leaving others alone.

Comment: I did that originally, however got berated for not being MCVE for including information about the full context (without the full script keeping it minimal), a diff link showing the cases that worked, as well as demonstration of a snip of those cases only (minimized).  I have since deleted that thread.  Even still, your code works, but does not address `CC_DENY`'s value specifically.  Ed did clear it up - replace the `+` with a `*` and it works.

Comment: The initial block I posted was no where even close to 1500 words.  I did cover all edge cases, however the mess that followed and addendums, were prompted by request to not go and look at diff, versions, further highlighting of the edge cases I had already covered, and so on.